# Swift app that allows two users to see a live updates drawing canvas

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build a swift app that would allow a user on one side to draw an image that will be updated in nearly real time on the other user's device, somewhat as if they were drawing on a whiteboard in person.

Anyone have any tips or places where I should start? I'm relatively new to swift. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Realm](https://realm.io) is exactly what you are looking for.

[Real time collaboration in as little as 10 lines of code](https://realm.io)

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This requires a persistent line of communication between your mobile device(s) and your server. Websockets allow this type of communication. I haven't implemented them myself so I can't provide implementation details, but there are plenty of resources available online.

[Sockets with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466665/sockets-with-swift)

[Websockets Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll look into those!