# Trouble converting NSData Objective-C code to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdata, core-bluetooth

I've been having issues converting an Objective-C snippet to Swift that uses `NSData` and `CoreBluetooth`. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097710/swift-3-changes-for-getbytes-method/39925609?noredirect=1#comment77390900_39925609) and a couple others dealing with `NSData` in Swift but haven't had any success.

**Objective-C Snippet:**

```
- (CGFloat) minTemperature
{
    CGFloat result = NAN;
    int16_t value = 0;

    // characteristic is a CBCharacteristic
    if (characteristic) { 
        [[characteristic value] getBytes:&value length:sizeof (value)];
        result = (CGFloat)value / 10.0f;
    }
    return result;
}
```

What I have so far in Swift (not working):

```
func minTemperature() -> CGFloat {
    let bytes = [UInt8](characteristic?.value)
    let pointer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes)
    let fPointer = pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: Int16.self, capacity: 2) { return $0 }
     value = Int16(fPointer.pointee)

    result = CGFloat(value / 10) // not correct value

    return result
}
```

Does the logic look wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error is in

```
let fPointer = pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: Int16.self, capacity: 2) { return $0 }
```

because the rebound pointer `$0` is only valid inside the closure and must
not be passed to the outside. Also the capacity should be `1` for a
single `Int16` value. Another problem is the integer division in

```
result = CGFloat(value / 10)
```

which truncates the result (as already [observed by the4kman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45287524/1187415)).

Creating an `[UInt8]` array from the data is not necessary, the
`withUnsafeBytes()` method of `Data` can be used instead.

Finally you could return `nil` (instead of "not a number") if no
characteristic value is given:

```
func minTemperature() -> CGFloat? {
    guard let value = characteristic?.value else {
        return nil
    }
    let i16val = value.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<Int16>) in
        ptr.pointee
    }
    return CGFloat(i16val) / 10.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the return value optional and check if `characteristic` is nil in the beginning with a `guard`. You should also explicitly convert the value to `CGFloat`, then divide it by 10.

```
func minTemperature() -> CGFloat? {
    guard characteristic != nil else {
        return nil
    }

    let bytes = [UInt8](characteristic!.value)
    let pointer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes)
    let fPointer = pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: Int16.self, capacity: 2) { return $0 }
    let value = Int16(fPointer.pointee)

    result = CGFloat(value) / 10

    return result
}
```

Comment: Casting value likes that gives the error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(_)'"