# OutputStream.write doesn't send the complete data but only a fixed amount

Tags: ios, swift, iostream, data-sharing

I'm sending a video via `OutputStream.write(_maxLength:)` but the write method doesn't send all the data bytes but only a fixed amount every time.
The total data count is `videoData.count = 7357450` but the bytes written(returned by `outputStream.write`) is only `131768`.

This is the method for writing to output stream.

```
extension OutputStream {
    func write(data: Data) -> Int {
        return data.withUnsafeBytes { write($0, maxLength: data.count) }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code?
Is there a way to increase the .write capacity?

Note: This is not related to this question: [Writing Data to an NSOutputStream in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090320/writing-data-to-an-nsoutputstream-in-swift-3). This question asks how to write while my question is about the limits of writing data.

Comment: Okay got it! But make sure there is a limit while writing to any stream, and for that you must read documentation.

Comment: I haven't been able to find much information about this topic, could you please direct me towards some relevant info ?

Comment: You can read this source (http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.pdf) and I came to know this https://prnt.sc/oaxyll

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll look through these.