# NSData.bytes[subscript] in Swift 5

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert this piece of code to Swift:

```
NSData *testData = [@"Whatever" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    void (^whatever)(NSOutputStream *) = ^(NSOutputStream *stream) {
        [stream open];
        NSRange myRange = {0};
        while (myRange.location < testData.length) {
            myRange.location += myRange.length;
            myRange.length = 4096;

            if (myRange.location + myRange.length > testData.length) {
                myRange.length = testData.length - myRange.location;
            }

            [stream write:&(testData.bytes[myRange.location])
                       maxLength:myRange.length];
        }
        [stream close];
    };
```

Unfortunately, i am really stuck on `&(testData.bytes[myRange.location])`.

The swift converters i found online don't process that part at all, and Swift compiler complains that:

> Value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' has no subscripts

The examples with `.withUnsafeBytes` don't show how to get the bytes pointer at a specific location.

Here's the swift:

```
        let testData = "Whatever".data(using: .utf8)!
        let whatever: ((OutputStream) -> Void)? = { stream in
            stream.open()
            var myRange = NSRange()
            while myRange.location < testData.count {
                myRange.location += myRange.length
                myRange.length = 4096

                if myRange.location + myRange.length > testData.count {
                    myRange.length = testData.count - myRange.location
                }
                // the next line doesn't work
                stream.write(testData.bytes[myRange.location], maxLength: myRange.length)
            }
            stream.close()
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at [Writing Data to an NSOutputStream in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38090320/1187415) and in particular the Swift 5 answer.

Comment: @MartinR did you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301838/2057955 That takes the entire data in one go, not chunked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of C, where taking the address of a subscripted pointer is equivalent to adding an offset to the pointer:

```
&pointer[index] == pointer + index
```

In your case,

```
[stream write:&(testData.bytes[myRange.location]) maxLength:myRange.length];
```

is equivalent to

```
[stream write:testData.bytes + myRange.location maxLength:myRange.length];
```

This shows that the problem is not really about subscripting, but about how to obtain a pointer to the element storage of a `Data` value at an offset.

Obtaining a pointer to the element storage is done using `withUnsafeBytes()` and binding the raw pointer to an `UInt8` pointer (see also [Writing Data to an NSOutputStream in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090320/writing-data-to-an-nsoutputstream-in-swift-3)). This can be combined with *slicing* (`testData[offset...]`) to write the data at a specified offset:

```
let testData = "Whatever".data(using: .utf8)!
let whatever: ((OutputStream) -> Void)? = { stream in
    stream.open()
    var position = 0
    while position < testData.count {
        let length = min(4096, testData.count - position)
        let amount =  testData[position...].withUnsafeBytes {
            stream.write($0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!, maxLength: length)
        }
        if amount <= 0 {
            // Error or EOF
            break
        }
        position += amount
    }
    stream.close()
}
```

Note that the `write` method returns the number of bytes actually written (or `0` or `-1`). When writing to anything but a plain file (e.g. a TCP socket, a pipe, ...) this can be *less than* the value of the `maxLength` parameter.

Alternatively you can obtain the pointer to the element storage once, and then increment it by the amount of data written:

```
let testData = "Whatever".data(using: .utf8)!
let whatever: ((OutputStream) -> Void)? = { stream in
    stream.open()
    var length = testData.count
    testData.withUnsafeBytes {
        var ptr = $0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!
        while length > 0 {
            let amount = stream.write(ptr, maxLength: min(length, 4096))
            if amount <= 0 { break }
            ptr += amount
            length -= amount
        }
    }
    stream.close()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete `bytes` and subscript the Data object directly.

Comment: That gives me `Cannot convert value of type 'UInt8' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>'`

Comment: Gives it to you where? You have shown no Swift code at all! You asked how to get the byte at a specific location and that is how.

Comment: On the same line... `stream.write(testData[myRange.location], maxLength: myRange.length)`